# How to use a duplicate search in a SELECT request in SQL

Tags: mysql

I found several duplicate line with this request :

```
SELECT UID1, UID2, COUNT(*)
FROM TableGroup
GROUP BY UID1, UID2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Like this :

```
UID1    UID2
2353    2585    2
2354    2585    2
2355    2585    2
2357    2583    2
```

UID1 is related with an other table I called NameUID1

```
2353 Name1
2354 Name2
2355 Name3
2357 Name4
```

UID2  is related with an other table I called NameUID2

```
2585 OtherName1
2583 OtherName2
```

I don't know how to merge  the first request for using it in a new request for have the name associated with the UNID1 et UNID2 Like this :

```
UID1    UID2
Name1   OtherName1
Name2   OtherName1
Name3   OtherName1
Name4   OtherName2
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and joins

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT UID1, UID2, COUNT(*)
    FROM TableGroup
    GROUP BY UID1, UID2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT u1.name, u2.name FROM cte
INNER JOIN NameUID1 u1 ON u1.UID1=u2.UID2
INNER JOIN NameUID2 u2 ON u2.UID2=u2.UID2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the select clause as rdge Table and join them all

```
SELECT t1.Mames,t3.Names
FROM NameUID1 t1
INNER JOIN (    SELECT UID1, UID2
    FROM TableGroup
    GROUP BY UID1, UID2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.UID1  = t2.UID1 
INNER JOIN 
NameUID2 t3 ON t2.UID2 = t3.UID2
```